# Does not print everything from sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a forum for my school project. Now i want to get the data out of my database so i can print it and people can see and react to it. Now i have the problem that it only print the commenters post and not the creators post. I will ad some picture and the code so you guys can undestand. (PS. i have a form on the previous page where you can search)
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho6oB.png)
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jctTa.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title><?php echo $_GET["search"];?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //navbar
    include "./include/nav.php";
    //database connection
    include "./include/conn.php";

    $search = $_GET["search"];

    if($search == ""){
        // if empty return to index
        echo "
            <script>alert('thread does not exist')</script>
            <script>window.location = './index.php'</script>
            ";
    } else {
        //check if data exist
        $sql = "SELECT thread, post, username, status FROM post WHERE thread = ? ";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($search));    

        $data = $query->fetch();

        if($data){
            // print data if exist
            echo "<div class='padding'>";
            foreach ($query as $test) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["thread"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["post"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["username"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["status"] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>" . "</br>";
            }
                echo "<button onclick='comment()'>Comment</button>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div id='test'>";
        } else {
            // if data does not exist return to index
            echo "
            <script>alert('thread does not exist')</script>
            <script>window.location = './index.php'</script>
            ";
        }

    }
?>
<script>
    // if comment btn is pressed save thread name and send to comment.php
    function comment() {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
        "<?php 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['thread'] = $data['thread'];
        ?>";
        window.location.assign("./comment.php")
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you never use `$data`, which holds the first fetched row. My suggestion: use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` and iterate `$data` instead of `$query`.

Comment: `fetchAll()` should not be used when the intention is to immediately iterate the result set in the same layer (fringe cases excluded -- like passing a special argument to it to modify the result set structure).  If you are going to iterate the result set, then fetch the row data in a loop.

Comment: Please... Try your code first without java code... Only php... Then add html.. Then java.... Clear your code..... Make fetchAll()....  Call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used the data that i got out of the database. I should have printed it like this:

```
if($data){
            // print data if exist
            echo "<div class='padding'>";
            foreach ($data as $test) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["thread"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["post"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["username"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $test["status"] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>" . "</br>";
            }
                echo "<button onclick='comment()'>Comment</button>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div id='test'>";
        } else {
            // if data does not exist return to index
            echo "
            <script>alert('thread does not exist')</script>
            <script>window.location = './index.php'</script>
            ";
        }

    }
```